# Bundle eclipse.ini with product in deployable feature?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am exporting a deployable feature which bundles a product plugin. Within this product plugin, I have created a customized welcome page and a splashscreen. Now I want that after installation of the exported deployable feature, the `eclipse.ini` file will be changed in order to pass my own product plugin to the argument `-product` and `-showsplash`. Currently, users need to make these changes manually after installation of the feature. Is there a better way, for example to bundle the modified `eclipse.ini` with the product?

Comment: Normally you build a complete RCP and ship that (this is what things like Aptana and STS do).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I only ship deployable features. Can this be achieved through a custom `config.ini`?

Comment: You might be able to do it with the p2 installer (see [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/167541/) for example). I am not a p2 expert so I don't know if that works with deployable features. In general people do not expect a feature to change the product that runs.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will check that.

Answer (score 0):

In your feature's build.properties file, you can have it include arbitrary files with a line like this:

```
root.win32.win32.x86=absolute:file:eclipse.ini
```

Information on what can be included in the build.properties file can be found [here](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/reference/pde_feature_generating_build.htm?cp=4_3_1_1).

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse ini is normally created during build or installation. The content can be given inside the [ProductConfiguration Editor - Launching](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/editors/product_editor/launching.htm). You can specify your parameters there and they will be entered into your build generated p2 product. When the product is installed the parameter will be added to the eclipse.ini file.